# css: creating white space between lines in one paragraph

Tags: css

I have a multiline paragraph of variable width.
The background of each line should be a solid color but in between two lines I would like to see the background image.

Example:
http://piccsy.com/2012/03/the-ysp-herself

I have tried to set the `line-height` but this will not create space in between the lines.

Comment: You cant style `line-boxes` directly so you would need to wrap each line in a tag, which means it wouldnt auto flow, you would need to use these to form manual line breaks.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know that you can do this automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
span {
    background-color:grey;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:18px;
}
```

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/YaB5j/)

Comment: The problem seems to be with the `<p>` changing it to `<span>` did the trick. Thanks a lot!
Will get accepted as soon as SO lets me :)

Comment: <p> is a block-level element, <span> is inline-level .. that's the trick ... and, it's not a 'problem' it's a normal behavior. ;)

Comment: I meant 'my problem' not a fault in the system. Thanks for the further  explanation, though.